# Why is my proof of the integral of the dirac function being equal to 1 incorrect?

Tags: integration, limits, dirac-delta

I know that there are questions on this website on how to prove that the integral of the Dirac function is $1$. However, I am interested in knowing why my proof is wrong and if there is a way to salvage it. So here's the question :

> The Dirac delta function can be defined by the limit of a short pulse: $$\delta(t-t_0) = \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}({f_{\Delta}(t)})$$ where $f_{\Delta}(t) = \frac{1}{\Delta}$ for $t_0\leq t\leq t_0 + \Delta$ and $f_{\Delta}(t) = 0$ otherwise. Convince yourself that the integral $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta(t-t_0) dt = 1$ if $t_1\leq t_0 \leq t_2 $

Here's my approach:
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta(t-t_0) dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}({f_{\Delta}(t)}) dt$$ $$=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{\Delta})dt$$ $$=\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{\Delta})\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt$$ $$=\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{\Delta}) \cdot (t_2-t_1)$$ $$=\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}(\frac{t_2-t_1}{\Delta})$$ If we let $t_1 = t_0$ and $t_2 = t_0 + \Delta$, then we get $$\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}(\frac{\Delta}{\Delta})$$ $$ = 1$$

Here's why I doubt my proof.

First, in the third line of my development, I took out the limit from the integral. My reasoning behind the maneuver is that this limit does not depend on $t$ and therefore I can treat it as a constant. However, upon re-reading my proof, I am wondering if I am really "allowed" to do this. Since I am treating the limit as a constant, I am assuming that it exists and is finite, which is not the case, right? (since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1/x)$ does not exist).

Secondly, to get to the 6th line, I defined $t_2 = t_0 + \Delta$. Am I allowed to do this? I defined it that way only because it was mathematically convenient, not because it actually makes sense, which is why I doubt its validity.

I personally think that the proof is incorrect, but I'm not sure. Perhaps one could argue otherwise and I would be interested to know how.

So, can you confirm to me that my proof is incorrect, and can you please let me know if there's anything I can do to "salvage" it, or if I need to try another approach

Comment: My understanding of defining the delta function usually has that the limit is actually outside the integral to begin with. You're right to be concerned with exchanging the order of operations here. I would understand/ be more comfortable with the definition if it looked like
$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta(t - t_0) = dt = \lim_{t\to t_0} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f_\Delta(t) \ dt. $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem begins with the definition of Dirac delta
$$ \delta(t-t_0) = \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}({f_{\Delta}(t)}) \tag{1} $$
which is **not** an equality of functions since the pointwise
limit does not exist at $\,t=t_0.\,$ Thus, your very first
step of writing
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta(t-t_0) dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}
 \lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}({f_{\Delta}(t)}) dt \tag{2} $$
is problematic unless interpreted as an appropriate kind
of integral suitable for distributions.
More problematic is that, as the Wikipedia article
[Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)
states:

> [...] it is understood that the limit is always taken *outside the integral*.

Next, your step equating the integral to
$$ =\lim_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{\Delta})\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt \tag{3} $$
is flawed because you should **not** be integrating the constant function
$1$ but instead the function $\,\Delta f_\Delta(t).\,$
As the definition states:

> $f_{\Delta}(t) = \frac{1}{\Delta}$ for $t_0\leq t\leq t_0 + \Delta$ and $f_{\Delta}(t) = 0$ otherwise.

What you are integrating here has the value $1$ for $t_0\leq t\leq t_0 + \Delta$
and $0$ otherwise. Thus the integral is **not** $\,(t_2-t_1)\,$ as you have it in your next step.

Comment: Thank you very much